# Entity Framework Core 6 TPH ignore discriminator column for specific query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

So first off, let me say that I know this question is an anti-pattern, but software evolves and this is where I am.

I have 2 Entities in my system `Course` and `Event`. Both inherit from `CourseEvent` and share some common properties and also each entity has its own properties. These represent live events at a conference. Once the live event has aired, we convert it to a `Course`.

The problem we have, is that once we convert an event into a course, the queries that return events to the users are no longer including those entity types..this includes on the schedule and mobile app specifically...this hasn't been a huge problem, but I think its a better user experience if I can find a way to return the old data. I eventually will refactor the system to just have a CourseEvent, but that will be a large overhaul.

I want to find a way, (even a hacky way if necessary) to tell a query to materialize as an event, even though the discriminator in the database is currently set to 'Course'.

Could I use an interceptor to set the value read from SQL or something like that?

Comment: Add a 3rd TPH type with properties that match both, mapped to the same column names?

Answer (score 0):

Your `DbContext` can expose a `DbSet` for CourseEvents alongside Courses and Events. So for instance if you want all courses and events for a particular user:

```
var coursesAndEvents = _context.CourseEvents
    .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
    .ToList();
```

You don't need to change existing code that might be set up to use a Courses or Events DbSet.

Comment: That wont have the specific columns/properties of the "events" class. Only the shared ones.

Comment: It will if you filter or inspect. If you want the courses, `var courses = courseAndEvents.OfType<Event>()` or individually: `if (courseOrEvent is Event)`, or do it dynamically /w `dynamic` and leave it a runtime validation concern. If you want to read events as if they were courses it isn't a legal cast/impersonation in C# unless Event extends Course and even if it were supported, you still wouldn't see Event-specific fields.